# getting row wise data from the database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table named **allocate** like this

```
CREATE TABLE allocate(
    mid int(10), 
    pid int(20),
    day1 int(2),
    day2 int(2),
    ...
    day31 int (2)
);
```

In `mid`, I have the a number corresponding to a month (1 is January, 2 is February, etc.). In day1 through day31, I have numerical values. I'm now trying to retrieve and update data for the same, but I am unable to do it.

I'm using the following code to retrieve each month's data:

```
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");


$sql = "select * from allocate where product_id = '".$product_id."' "; // 

$res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
    $day1 = $row['day1'];
    $day2 = $row['day2'];
    $day3 = $row['day3'];
    $day4 = $row['day4'];
    $day5 = $row['day5']; 
    $day6 = $row['day6'];
    $day7 = $row['day7'];
    $day8 = $row['day8'];
    $day9 = $row['day9'];
    $day10 = $row['day10'];
    $day11 = $row['day11'];
    $day12 = $row['day12'];
    $day13 = $row['day13'];
    $day14 = $row['day14'];
    $day15 = $row['day15'];
    $day16 = $row['day16'];
    $day17 = $row['day17'];
    $day18 = $row['day18'];
    $day19 = $row['day19'];
    $day20 = $row['day20'];
    $day21 = $row['day21'];
    $day22 = $row['day22'];
    $day23 = $row['day23'];
    $day24 = $row['day24'];
    $day25 = $row['day25'];
    $day26 = $row['day26'];
    $day27 = $row['day27'];
    $day28 = $row['day28'];
    $day29 = $row['day29'];
    $day30 = $row['day30'];
    $day31 = $row['day31'];
}
echo $day1;
```

Here, I am getting the values for January day1 to day31. How do I solve this? Insertion into allocation is properly happening.

Comment: Is this all your code? You say you want to update the data, but there is no update state.

Comment: 1st i want to retrieve the data completely, After selecting everything... it should show the data for all the month... how to get that

Comment: It would be better to shrink the variable assignments like the table itself to improve readability, on another note whats the error or is it just returning 1 row while you have more than one in the table

Comment: How is your query getting the values for January? Your table columns are `mid` and `pid`, but you are using `WHERE product_id =` and there is no reference to the month.

Comment: @Sean I guess the error is in just typing out the create table syntax, and that he is getting all the months through that query and looping through them to process results, that part seems fine to me...

Answer (score 1):

in you sql query, you are refering to the field `product_id`

```
select * from allocate where product_id =
```

which doesn't exist in your schema. Also to print out the data row wise you should have had the `echo` inside the while loop which loops through your result row wise.